# What is the purpose of interpreting claim language into plain English?

Tags: discussion

This practice seems like it is ripe for misinterpretation of the claim language itself. How do we make sure that we aren't losing necessary meaning when doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the template calls for this, but a reason might be to have an explict "translation" into plain English that can be commented upon and edited rather than each reader privately producing their own misinformation.